# Python argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm getting an error when posting the following json: `{"email":"test@test.com", "password":"12345", "repeatPassword":"12345"}`

I'm using Django-Rest_framework, so I think I might have set up something wrong?

This is the serializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    repeatPassword = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True, label="Re-enter Password")
    def validate(self, attrs):
        passwordValue = attrs["password"]
        repeatPasswordValue = attrs["repeatPassword"]


        if passwordValue is not None and passwordValue != "":
            if repeatPasswordValue is None or repeatPasswordValue == "":
                raise serializers.ValidationError("Please re-enter your password")

        if passwordValue != repeatPasswordValue:
            serializers.ValidationError("Passwords must match")

        return attrs

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("email", "username", "password")
        read_only_fields = ("username",)
        write_only_fields = ("password",)
```

The view is just a basic `ModelViewSet` for the `User` model that I have

Maybe I configured the url.py file incorrectly? This is what I have for the urlpatterns.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^user/$', UserViewSet.as_view({"get": "list", "put": "create"})))
```

Comment: Which line do you get the `'NoneType' is not iterable` error from?

Comment: `passwordValue = attrs["password"]` That's the line.

Comment: This seems to imply that attrs is None. What does type(attrs) report?

Comment: @Iteria Provide the full traceback please..

Comment: @MultimediaMike you're right the value of attr is None, but I'm not sure how that's possible.

Comment: @mariodev here ya go: http://pastebin.com/vnmjb5C4

Comment: @Iteria Do you have `validate_password` method in you serializer? Seems like you do and you return incorrect value from it..

Comment: I do have a `validate_password` method and you're right. It looks like I forgot to return a value from it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you may have omitted some code. I had the same issue caused a validator function not returning the attrs variable so my code looked like this:

```
def validate_province(self, attrs, source):
    // unimportant details
```

and this solved it:

```
...
    def validate_province(self, attrs, source):
        // unimportant details
        return attrs
...
```

---

On a side note, you forgot to raise one of your exceptions:

```
...
    if passwordValue != repeatPasswordValue:
        serializers.ValidationError("Passwords must match")
...
```

change it to:

```
...
    if passwordValue != repeatPasswordValue:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Passwords must match")
...
```